# SharePoint 2019 JSON AST column formatting

Tags: sharepoint-server, modern-experience, json-formatting, 2019, column-formatting

I would like to realize the following:

If the date in a column is more than 40 days old, the background should turn orange. If the date is more than 80 days in the past, the background should turn red. Otherwise the background should turn green.

The following code should actually be correct. No errors are displayed. However, all dates that are more than 40 days in the past turn orange. No date turns red or green.

Perhaps someone can help me here.

```
{
"elmType": "div",
"txtContent": "@currentField",
"style":{
"background-color":
{"operator": "?", "operands":
 [
  {
   "operator": "<=",
   "operands":
    ["@currentField",
     {"operator": "-",
      "operands": ["@now",4320000000]
     }
    ]
  },"#ff8a00",
  {                          
   "operator": "<=",
   "operands":
    ["@currentField",
     {"operator": "-",
      "operands": ["@now",6912000000]
     }
    ]
  },"#ff0000",
    "#00ff00"
  ]
 }            
}
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try using SharePoint JSON column formatting like below for your date column:

```
{
  "$schema": "https://developer.microsoft.com/json-schemas/sp/v1/column-formatting.schema.json",
  "elmType": "div",
  "txtContent": "[$StartDate.displayValue]",
  "style": {
    "padding-left": "15px",
    "color": "white",
    "background-color": {
      "operator": "?",
      "operands": [
        {
          "operator": "<=",
          "operands": [
            "[$StartDate]",
            {
              "operator": "-",
              "operands": [
                "@now",
                6912000000
              ]
            }
          ]
        },
        "#ff0000",
        {
          "operator": "?",
          "operands": [
            {
              "operator": "<=",
              "operands": [
                "[$StartDate]",
                {
                  "operator": "-",
                  "operands": [
                    "@now",
                    4320000000
                  ]
                }
              ]
            },
            "#ff8a00",
            "#00ff00"
          ]
        }
      ]
    }
  }
}
```

Where `[$StartDate]` is an **internal name** of your date column in SharePoint list in this format: `[$InternalNameOfColumn]`.

You can get the internal name of your SharePoint list columns by following this article: [How to find the Internal name of columns in SharePoint Online?](https://ganeshsanapblogs.wordpress.com/2023/04/17/how-to-find-the-internal-name-of-sharepoint-columns/).

Comment: Output: https://imgur.com/PzRY9DZ

Comment: I'm close to the finish line.

The backgrounds color correctly depending on the date.
However, the fields are now empty and no longer show the date.
If I remove 
`".displayValue"` 
from 
`"txtContent": "[$StartDate.displayValue]"`, 
the date including time is displayed.

I don't want to see the time.

I'm starting to feel like a bit of an idiot. That can not be that hard.

Comment: Ok, problem solved.
If I swap "[$StartDate.displayValue]" for "@currentField", the date is there again.

Thanks for help

Comment: Yes, `@currentField` should also work as you are applying formatting for same date field and trying to show the value of same date field.